# How to count all uppercase characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, equality, mutation, toupper

I stuck on a function that supposed to count upper letters in a string. But instead the counter results in 0 and I've no idea where I made a mistake.

```
const bigLettersCount = (str) => {
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
    if (str[i].toUpperCase() === str[i]) {
    result += i;
    }
    return result;
   }
  }
  bigLettersCount('HeLLo')
```

Comment: You are returning after the first iteration of the loop. Also you are incrementing your count by i and not 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code like below. It will work.

```
const bigLettersCount = (str) => {
let result = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
  if (str[i].toUpperCase() === str[i]) {
    result++;
  }
}
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to do the same.

```js
const str = 'HeLLo';

console.log(
  (str.match(/[A-Z]/g) || '').length
)
```

Comment: This writing form is new for me and I don't understand it. Is there any way to improve my function with a loop method?

Comment: @Markus : it's simply extracting all single capital character from the string into an array and checking the length

Answer (score 0):

You can use [charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) and if it is between 65 (A) and 90 (Z) it means it is an upper case letter:

```js
const bigLettersCount = (str) => {
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
    if (str.charCodeAt(i) > 64 && str.charCodeAt(i) <91 ) {
      result += 1;
    }
   }
   return result
  }
  
console.log(bigLettersCount('HeLLo'))
```